# Can I make my android phone automatically factory reset if the pin is entered incorrectly too many times?

Tags: android, security, mobile, customization

I am traveling overseas in a region where I would prefer my contacts and emails not be accessed if I am forced to unlock my phone. I would like to set up my android (Pixel 3a) phone to automatically perform a factory reset if I entered the pin number wrong three times.

Is this (still) possible? (I believe my wife's old Samsung had this function a few years ago)

How might I go about setting this up?